# Unsupported get request. Object with ID '{USER_ID}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am getting this from Facebook webhook. I am trying to get the sender's name and profile picture.

```
<pre>
{
  "object": "page",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "172916740162087",
      "time": 1609667491,
      "changes": [
        {
          "value": {
            "from": {
              "id": "2529118547136023",
              "name": "Md Abid Hasan Nayem"
            },
            "post": {
              "status_type": "added_photos",
              "is_published": true,
              "updated_time": "2021-01-03T09:51:29+0000",
              "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/CodeWareLTD/posts/851154192338335",
              "promotion_status": "inactive",
              "id": "172916740162087_851154192338335"
            },
            "message": "Happy new year",
            "post_id": "172916740162087_851154192338335",
            "comment_id": "851154192338335_853191445467943",
            "created_time": 1609667489,
            "item": "comment",
            "parent_id": "172916740162087_851154192338335",
            "verb": "add"
          },
          "field": "feed"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
</pre>
```

When I am sending request with the user id /{USER_ID}?access_token=token then it's returning this error.
Whereas I have all the required permissions approved.

```
<pre>
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "ABtpgYvcMuaA_jQcW8Fdi3M"
  }
}
</pre>
```

I opened a bug report, but they told me it's ok as per the current Facebook system design. But
still, I'm unable to get the user's first name, last name, and profile picture.
Bug Report Link: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/887826828623849/.
Please, help me to get the exact API to get the sender's name & profile picture.

my currently successfully reviewed permissions are:
email,
pages_manage_metadata,
pages_read_engagement,
pages_show_list,
pages_messaging,
pages_read_user_content,
public_profile,
pages_manage_engagement,
pages_manage_posts

Comment: What _type_ of access token are you using?

Comment: @CBroe I am using Page access token.

Comment: Then it is probably a case of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile#availability - you can only get user information via a page-scoped ID, if the user performed one of the “opt-in” actions listed there in the next section. The fact that they merely commented on a page post, does not seem to qualify.